# Typescript - IntrinsicAttributes and children type issues when typing React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am migrating my React files to `.tsx` and have come across this issue.

**Footer.tsx**

```
const Footer = ({ children, inModal }) => (
    <footer className={'(inModal ? " in-modal" : "") }>
        <div>
            {children}
        </div>
    </footer>
);

export default Footer;
```

**ParentComponent.tsx**

```
import Footer from 'path/to/Footer';

export class ParentComponent extends React.Component<{ showSomething: (() => void) }> {
    render() {
        return (
            <Footer>
                <Button onClick={() => this.props.showSomething()}>Add</Button>
            </Footer>
        );
    }
}
```

There is a red underline underneath the `<Footer>` tag with the error:

> [ts] Type '{ children: Element; }' is not assignable to type
>   'IntrinsicAttributes & { children: any; inModal: any; }'.   Type '{
>   children: Element; }' is not assignable to type '{ children: any;
>   inModal: any; }'.
>       Property 'inModal' is missing in type '{ children: Element; }'.

I'm not quite sure how to decipher what that means. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you still get the error if you give `inModal` a default value of `false` in your `Footer` component? `const Footer = ({ children, inModal = false }) ...`

Comment: No, the error goes away when I give a default value.  Would you mind explaining why that is and I can accept your answer?

Comment: I think CRice gave a very nice answer below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error is indicating that the `Footer` component requires a prop `inModal` to be passed to it. To fix the issue, you can either:

Give it a default value:

```
const Footer = ({ children, inModal = false }) => ...
```

Tell typescript that it's optional:

```
const Footer = ({ children, inModal }: {children: any, inModal?: boolean}) => ...
```

Or explicitly provide that prop whenever you use the footer:

```
<Footer inModal={false}> ... </Footer>
```

Comment: Apologies for resurrecting an old question, but could you explain _how_ the error means that? What are `IntrinsicAttributes`? What's going on with the type system that causes the absence of a default value to result in that error? (I'm seeing the same error, but these solutions didn't fix it for me; I'm seeking a deeper understanding.)

Comment: @JakeRobb In this case the whole deduction came from only the last part of the error: `Property 'inModal' is missing in type '{ children: Element; }`, which spells it out pretty directly. The type system shows an error since the prop is marked required; it can't be left unspecified as it was originally written (see answer for detail on that). As for `IntrinsicAttributes`? It is the type representing the props that all react components must accept (and fyi: there is only one such prop, `key`, an optional `string | number`). If you are really stuck, perhaps consider asking a new question?

Answer (score 0):

I see your code and find you have not specify the type of inModal props, I believe it’s a good prectice to define interface like that:

```
export class ParentComponent extends React.Component<{ showSomething: (() => void) }> {
```

you can modify this something like this:

```
interface FooterPropsType{
showSomething?:()=> void,
isModal?: boolean,
}

export class ParentComponent extends React.Component<FooterPropsType> {
```